# Projecting a 3D surface onto a 2D plane (unfolding/unwrapping) in Python

Tags: python, 3d, projection, surface, plane

I don't know if I am just searching for the wrong terms but I cannot find any examples of code to do this. I have a surface that is almost flat but not quite and would like to "unfold" or "unwrap" it so that it is all in one plane while keeping the distance between points the same. From what I understand this process is called developing a surface, but all I can find are old mathematical papers on the process would be quite a bit of work trying to recreate.

Can't really provide any code for it but I have data in the form of points like

```
coords = [(x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2),..., (x_n, y_n, z_n)]
```

It doesn't seem like it should be that hard to do but maybe I am mistaken, any input?

Comment: Don't think this is possible in the general case. Consider the case of four points arranged into a pyramid, whose edges are all one unit long. There's no way to flatten all the points into a plane so that they're still all one unit away from every other point.

Comment: @Kevin It's true that it is not possible in the general case, but it is possible for devolopable surfaces. Imagine a A4 paper that u scrunch up to a weird shape, you could always untangle it and have the distances be the same as before.

Comment: I think I understand what you're getting at, but I don't think it can be accurately described as maintaining the distances of all point pairs. It's possible to fold a flat sheet of paper into the pyramid I described earlier, but it seems silly to say that a flat sheet of paper isn't a developable surface, so the _real_ constraints must be something more relaxed.

Comment: Hmm I guess the distance along the surface rather than the 3D distance is what I am thinking of